# Custom Authentication Class as a DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying make a custom authentication class (I've defined it in `views.py` file itself) as the **default authentication class** for my django project using django rest framework. Although I'm not sure if it is possible, it seems logical to be able to do this.

And I know the workaround for this by using `@authentication_classes` decorator in the views. But repeating the same thing over and over again seems illogical. The [official API GUIDE](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) too doesn't mention it. I'm hoping to be elucidated if any one of you ever encountered such a case and knows a solution.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    .
    .
    DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES: (
        'appname.views.CustomAuthentication',
    ),
    .
    .
}
```

`Could not import 'appname.views.CustomAuthentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'. ImportError: cannot import name views.`

Thanks

Comment: Hi, you should put the code for all the files. I am running into a similar issue and I don't know how to solve it exactly ... This seemed useful too : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/ , https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you are hitting an import loop, so moving your authentication class outside of your view file and into a dedicated file for the authentication class should solve the issue.

When you import `rest_framework.views` (or any generic view, including a viewset), it will automatically import all of your default authentication classes. So if you are importing views at the top of your views file (most likely) it will try to import the authentication class which is located *after* your import line. Because there will be a circular import, Python will raise an exception about the module not being able to be imported (`views` in this case), which is why you are getting the exception.

So just move your authentication class out into it's own file, `authentication.py` for example, and change your `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` to adjust for it.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    .
    .
    DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES: (
        'appname.authentication.CustomAuthentication',
    ),
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing the answer. You understood the problem correctly. And I too had stumbled on to the solution. But I am not able to understand what is causing the circular import here? Can you make a flow chart / step by step depiction of the scenario? It would be really helpful to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a solution to this. But I don't know why it's working. So, the trick is that you create an `authentication.py` file and put your `CustomAuthentication` there.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    .
    .
    DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES: (
        'appname.authentication.CustomAuthentication',
    ),
    .
    .
}
```

But I would still want to know why is this working? What if I want to use some other name of the file containing my `CustomAuthentication` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can add default authentication classes as

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('myproj.utils.authentication.CustomAuthentication1',
'myproj.utils.authentication.CustomAuthentication2',)
}
```

When CustomAuthentication1 fails it tries CustomAuthentication2 class authentication.

Give the path auth class path relative to your project.

Comment: As you can see in the question, that's what I did. Except I didn't create `utils` package under my app. I thought of creating the  Authentication class in my `views.py` itself. I don't understand why this doesn't work. Also, you can check my answer/workaround for this. BTW did you mean to use `myapp` instead of `myproj` ?

Comment: I mean to say add the complete path , from the project root directory.

Comment: Suppose there is a project named `myproj` and an app named `myapp` inside it. So, essentially you are saying to refer the `CustomAuthentication` class which is in `authentication.py` file like `myproj.myapp.authentication.CustomAuthentication` ? I don't mentioning the project name is necessary as the `myapp` is already in INSTALLED_APPS in the settings file.

Comment: Yes , the path should be in this format :::
myproj.myapp.authentication.CustomAuthentication
.. mentioning the path with respect to project root is essential.Change it relative to project path, it will definitely work, hope it helps :)

Comment: You may be right, but as I mentioned in my answer **it's working even without mentioning the path relative to project**. As the app is anyway installed in this project. It automatically finds the app from the root. There is something else going on here.